# R gsub wild card

Tags: r, wildcard, gsub

I'd like to delete a "*" from a character expression (in R). I am not up to speed sufficiently with the intricacies of gsub after reading the help page and trying google. Could someone suggest how I might do this?

Thanks,

Jonathan.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape twice: once for R and once for the regexp.

```
gsub("\\*","","a*b*c")
[1] "abc"
```

Comment: You posted this one hour ago? Refresh time of SO is terrible. :/

Comment: For a single character, you can also use square brackets: `gsub("[*]","","a*b*c")`.

Comment: `gsub("*", "", x, fixed = TRUE)` is another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
> x <- "It's always advisable to provide a *reproducible* example"
> gsub("\\*", "", x)
[1] "It's always advisable to provide a reproducible example"
```

Answer (score 0):

Other possibilities would be:

```
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", "a*b*c")

gsub("[*]", "", "a*b*c")
```